# Density plots in lattice that are proportional to the total group

Tags: r, visualization, lattice, density-plot

I am trying to create density plots in `lattice` where each estimate is proportional to the total group and not just to the subset.

This is possible using histograms, like so:

```
require(lattice)
set.seed(1)
sex <- factor(sample(c("Men", "Women"), 200, replace = T, prob = c(.3, .7)))
age <- rnorm(200, 50, 10)

histogram(~age | sex, type = "count")
```

[image: Imgur]

But how do I manage this using `densityplot()`? The `type = "count"` argument does not seem to work here.

Edit: This is the result I'm looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(sex, age)

ggplot(data, aes(age)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  facet_grid(~ sex)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: So what y-scale do you want for your plot? I'm not sure I understand what the desired output is.

Comment: Counts or some kind of proportional density estimate. Let me see if I can find a plot that describes what I want to do.